# Unable to run build gradle using gradle distribution 2.14.1 on adding rippleeffect library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The project was working fine but then when i tried usng ripple effect library by adding either of these two  -

```
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

The Gradle build process seems to be stuck in resolving dependencies : app debug compile and on canceling it, I get this log error

```
Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip'.
```

My build.gradle( Module app ) is -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.priyanshu.iitmandi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'

}
```

Also build gradle project is -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {

}
```

Getting this in console -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3.
     Required by:
         IITMandi:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/traex/rippleeffect/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/traex/rippleeffect/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.8.0.1:8080 [/10.8.0.1] failed: Connection timed out
      > Could not resolve com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/traex/rippleeffect/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/traex/rippleeffect/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.8.0.1:8080 [/10.8.0.1] failed: Connection timed out
```

I removed the proxy from settings but still here proxy is causing this error, how to correct this

[Solved] Problem solved on removing proxy from gradle.properties

Comment: Are you maybe behind a firewall or proxy that blocks your access to the dependencies?

Comment: @Henry Please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your build.gradle (project level) change the following

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven{ url "https://github.com/omadahealth/omada-nexus/raw/master/release" }
    }
```

You can find more at [here](https://github.com/omadahealth/LolliPin/issues/117)